# Entity Framework migration update-database error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usmdx.png)
I can't find exactly where I got the error because I took a break for a while, can you help me?

As I said, when I search for possibilities, I can't find it exactly. There was no problem when I said addmigration, but after I said update-database, I got an error like this.

Comment: What error did you actually get?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Hide Status
Error NU1202 The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.8 package is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.8 package supports: net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0) Demo_Product C:\Users\kkork\source\repos\Demo_Product\Demo_Product\Demo_Product.csproj 1
Error Package restore failed. Undoing package changes for 'Demo_Product'.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add :(. even though i do these updates i still get error i don't know exactly where is the problem this is my first asp.net project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to thank those who supported the comments. I deleted the tables in sql manually. I deleted the c# file by saying remove migration. I compiled the solution and created the migration again and by saying update, the tables were also dropped into the sql. no problem for now. delete and redo in such parts, I think it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your EF migration is trying to create an already existing table. To fix this error try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Categories
```

Comment: actually i have Categories